# android listview asynctask for textview and imageview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am trying to generate an android listview from a google books api call,
the google books api call return JSON data which one of these properties is a url for the book thumbnail so i thought about running a first asynctask that will call the JSON google books API and then onPostExecute i will run a second asynctask that will fetch the thumbnails and set them to an imageview however the behavior is not correct and the thumbnails are not associated with the correct row in the listview while fetching the thumbnails only the imageview in the first row is being updated and when the download completes the order is messed up.

below is an extract from my code:

```
private class BookSearchListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Book> mBooks = new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public BookSearchListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Book> books) {
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        this.mBooks = books;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_book_search_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_cover_thumbnail);
            holder.mTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
            holder.mAuthorTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Book b = mBooks.get(position);
        holder.mAuthorTextView.setText(TextUtils.join(", ", b.getAuthors()));
        holder.mTitleTextView.setText(b.getTitle());
        if (!b.getThumbnail().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            new ThumbNailDownloaderTask(holder.mImageView).execute(b.getThumbnail());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mBooks.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mBooks.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView mImageView;
    TextView mTitleTextView;
    TextView mAuthorTextView;
}

private class SearchBookTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private final String TAG = "SearchBookTask";

    private ArrayList<Book> mBooks = new ArrayList<>();

    private final static String BOOK_ITEMS_KEY = "items";
    private final static String BOOK_VOLUMEINFO_KEY = "volumeInfo";
    private final static String BOOK_IMAGELINKS_KEY = "imageLinks";
    private final static String BOOK_ID_KEY = "id";
    private final static String BOOK_TITLE_KEY = "title";
    private final static String BOOK_AUTHORS_KEY = "authors";
    private final static String BOOK_DESCRIPTION_KEY = "description";
    private final static String BOOK_THUMBNAIL_KEY = "thumbnail";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String bookQuery = params[0];
        String url = Uri.parse(ENDPOINT).buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("q", bookQuery)
                .appendQueryParameter("maxResults", "10")
                .appendQueryParameter("key", API_KEY)
                .build().toString();
        String result = new GoogleFetcher().getUrl(url);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mEmptyTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        if (s != null) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            constructBooksFromJSONResponse(s);
            mSearchResultListView.setAdapter(new BookSearchListAdapter(getActivity(), mBooks));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void constructBooksFromJSONResponse(String jsonResponse) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(jsonResponse));
            JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray(BOOK_ITEMS_KEY);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String bookId = "";
                if (currentObj.has(BOOK_ID_KEY)) {
                    bookId = currentObj.getString(BOOK_ID_KEY);
                }

                JSONObject volumeInfo = currentObj.getJSONObject(BOOK_VOLUMEINFO_KEY);
                String bookTitle = "";
                if (volumeInfo.has(BOOK_TITLE_KEY)) {
                    bookTitle = volumeInfo.getString(BOOK_TITLE_KEY);
                }

                JSONArray bookAuthors = new JSONArray();
                if (volumeInfo.has(BOOK_AUTHORS_KEY)) {
                    bookAuthors = volumeInfo.getJSONArray(BOOK_AUTHORS_KEY);
                }
                ArrayList<String> authors = new ArrayList<>();
                if (bookAuthors != null) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < bookAuthors.length(); j++) {
                        authors.add(bookAuthors.getString(j));
                    }
                }

                String bookDescription = "";
                if (volumeInfo.has(BOOK_DESCRIPTION_KEY)) {
                    bookDescription = volumeInfo.getString(BOOK_DESCRIPTION_KEY);
                }

                JSONObject imageLinks = volumeInfo.getJSONObject(BOOK_IMAGELINKS_KEY);
                String bookThumbnail = "";
                if (imageLinks.has(BOOK_THUMBNAIL_KEY)) {
                    bookThumbnail = imageLinks.getString(BOOK_THUMBNAIL_KEY);
                }

                Book b = new Book(bookId, authors, bookTitle, bookDescription, bookThumbnail);
                mBooks.add(b);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            mBooks.clear();
        }
    }
}

private class ThumbNailDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    private ThumbNailDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
    }

    private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String param) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(param);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return null;
            }
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            if (in != null) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the search button that triggers the search is something as follows:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_addbook, container, false);

    mSearchEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.book_title_search_field);
    mSearchButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    mSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String bookQuery = mSearchEditText.getText().toString();
            new SearchBookTask().execute(bookQuery);
        }
    });
return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `NetworkImageView` of `Volley` library. Get more info on its [image cache](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/google-io-2013-volley-image-cache-tutorial). You could find decent tutorial [here](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/android-volley-tutorial/) and [here](http://cypressnorth.com/mobile-application-development/setting-android-google-volley-imageloader-networkimageview/). It should make your `ListView` images load correctly.

Comment: I wanted to get a good understanding of why it is not behaving as it is supposed to be before using a third party library